# Spring data jpa. Find max if no result return default value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hql

I've implemented in my spring repository interface:

```
@Query("SELECT max(ch.id) FROM MyEntity ch")
Long getMaxId();
```

It works correctly if db is not empty. If I start my environment with test configuration (H2DB is used) - there is no data in the very beginning. And result returned by `getMaxId()` is **null**. I would like to have here **0**.

---

Is it possible to modify my `*JpaRepository` to have **0** result? If yes, how it should be modified?

Comment: Please tell me you're not doing that to generate IDs by yourself by incrementing the max every time you insert a new instance.

Comment: It's good point to have generated ids! And yes, I have ones. And I want to have only one id generator (igniteIdGenerator) someTimes it should repair its state (if cache repairs from db, igniteIdGenerator should be shifted).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` like :

```
@Query("SELECT coalesce(max(ch.id), 0) FROM MyEntity ch")
Long getMaxId();
```

If there are no data it will return 0 instead of null.