# Spring Data Jpa - Repository Query to get MaxID + 1?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.2

I went through [Spring CRUD repository: is there findOneByMaxXYZColumn()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801219/spring-crud-repository-is-there-findonebymaxxyzcolumn) and [Spring data jpa. Find max if no result return default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723744/spring-data-jpa-find-max-if-no-result-return-default-value/44723806) already, but I am looking more from the correct implementation perspective in concurrent environment.

In my application for `Employee` table, tools like ETL and NiFi will add Employee in to Postgres DB, but when inserting PK ID sequence will not be maintain it could be any unique value.

Ex: Any value of Employees like 399, 430, 439, 444 etc. If we look, IDs between 400 to 429 is not occupied, but when I add Employee though Admin UI, it should always 445 in this case. I am using Spring Boot JPA Repository queries

```
Long findFirstByEmployeeIdAsc();
```

This way I will get Max Id *(Maximum Value present in the PK column of the Employee Table)* and while saving record in to DB, I will do +1 to ID. Is this correct way to work with concurrent environment ?

Is there any way with the help of Jpa Repository query we can get MAXID+1 value? If we used this and what if any exception occures will that Id be consumed ?

Any pointers?

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully enough. Sorry about that. 1. you shouldn't read the whole entity just to get the max value. 2. You have to be prepared to get a duplicate key error from the database. Then you could try it again and again. The other option would be to lock the table. But then you block concurrent users

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - Thanks. Re 1. you shouldn't read the whole entity just to get the max value. As per `Long findFirstByEmployeeIdAsc();` I am just getting Max PK Id from DB. What is the best way to achieve all scenarios mentioned above ? I I get MAX+1 from DB somehow then that PK ID is consumed and concurrent users will get new PK ID. Only concern is that when expection occurs at save then I need to roll back that Id .. right ?

Comment: No you need to get a new one

Comment: Sorry I am not still clear. I think I should get Max Id from DB and manually do Max PK Id + 1 while doing repository save

Comment: yes. and the you do a save. This save can fail then you have to do this again set the id and save agin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, hope it will work:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT coalesce(max(id), 0) FROM Product") \
    public Long getMaxId();
```

Comment: @Toazzal Hossain Thanks! max() function works great in JPA queries

Comment: Thanks, @Anderson, the query will return max id, if no record is found then the query will return 0. You can increase by 1 for the next value.